# In limits, how is change of variables defined?

Tags: limits, substitution

When taking limits, for example as $n \rightarrow \infty$, it is obvious that $f(n)$ and $f(n + 1/2)$ approach the same limit. In both cases, you are essentially taking $f$ at higher and higher values, so the result should be the same.

But what is the formal justification of this rule?

EDIT:

Also, there are situations such as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is identical to $k \rightarrow 0$ in $1/k$. Thus, the limit of $f(n)$ is the same as the limit of $f(1/k)$, but, again, how to show it formally?

Comment: Unless you are using $n\to\infty$ for $n$ continuous (as opposed to the standard implicit notation that $n$ is integer-valued; people usually use $x\to\infty$ for the continuous case [citation needed]), your premise is false. Without strong assumptions on $f$, $f(n)$ and $f(n+1/2)$ need not have the same limit at all.

Comment: Your claim makes sense only if $n$ is assumed to be a continuous real variable and then the proof is essentially what you have given in your post. If $n\to\infty$ then $n+1/2\to\infty$ and *vice-versa* and therefore the limiting behavior of $f(n) $ and $f(n+1/2)$ is exactly same.

Answer (score 6):

"Obvious" or not, it is not always true that $f(n)$ and $f(n+1/2)$ have the same limit. Consider $f(x) = \sin^2(\pi x)$ for example.

So it's impossible to say how to prove it formally; in cases where it *is* true the proof depends on what function $f$ you're talking about.

Comment: I think the variable $n$ in this setting is meant to be a real number, not just an integer.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=x \iff (\forall \,\varepsilon>0 \,\exists N\in\mathbb{N} : n>N \implies|x_n-x|<\varepsilon)$$

Thus you can see that if $n>N$, then $n+\frac{1}{2}>N$ too. Similarly $2n$ or some function of $n$ under certain conditions.

EDIT:
obviously since $N$ is arbitrary, things like $\frac{n}{2}$ hold too because $2N$ is just as good a constant. And to answer to your edit, it's enough to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{k}=\infty$

EDIT2:
This answer is ultimately not correct. See the comments for Clement C. 's counterexample.

Comment: There is the slight issue of $n+1/2$ not being an integer, so $x_{n+1/2}$ doesn't really make sense here. In the sequential setting, writing $n>N$ implicitly comes with $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: True. Then $2n+1>2N$ I guess

Comment: But so the OP's question is based on trying to prove a false statement. The fact that the sequence $(f(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges says **nothing** about convergence of $(f(n+1/2))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: Look at David C. Ullrich's answer for a continuous example. But a simpler (not continuous) one may be $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1&\text {if }x\in\mathbb{N}\\ x& \text {otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer to say it's not correct

Comment: (To be fair: under some assumptions on $f$, it'll be, but you need these assumptions. For instance, it's true if $f$ is monotone.)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit, one can use the definition of limit to show that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=a$, then 
$$
\lim_{x\to b} f(g(x))=L.
$$